# fontconfg: Some fonts are too thin to read especially on external monitor

Tags: fonts, gui

I'm using Debian Bullseye on a laptop with a 2nd monitor attached. While fonts on the laptop screen are ok to read for my eyes, they can be unusually and uncomfortable thin on the external one. It is not the size that makes them hard to read, just they are so skinny that they almost blend into the background.

This screenshot from a java application though fails to really show the full extend as it looks better once embedded here as compared to the original.

[image]

I was playing around with fontconfig, disabling/enabling hinting and hintstyle and also this, trying to make all fonts bold as experiment:

```
<match target="font">
       <test qual="any" name="family"> 
            <string>sans</string> 
        </test>
   <edit name="weight" mode="assign"> 
          <const>bold</const>  
   </edit>
</match>
```

But so far not seeing a real improvement. Any suggestions what I can try to avoid too-thin fonts in general? Overriding fonts in Firefox is helping but not a fix for other applications. I would like to do it as low-level as possible.

Comment: I may close this, I noticed changing the settings on the monitor itself, especially reducing "Sharpness" and changing to "Text" overall mode, helps quite a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to you sceeenshot, your anti aliasing is not correctly setup. Depending on your DE, you could activate the anti aliasing and set "Hinting" to full.

On newer Debian/Ubuntu systems the folder you might tweak is `/etc/fonts/conf.d`. It contains only links to some of the available configurations. Make sure that links to some hinting.conf is contained there:

```
rwxrwxrwx 1 root root    31 Apr  6 12:09 10-antialias.conf -> ../conf.avail/10-antialias.conf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    36 Apr  6 12:09 10-hinting-slight.conf -> ../conf.avail/10-hinting-slight.conf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    40 Apr  6 12:09 10-scale-bitmap-fonts.conf -> ../conf.avail/10-scale-bitmap-fonts.conf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    39 Apr  6 12:09 11-lcdfilter-default.conf -> ../conf.avail/11-lcdfilter-default.conf
```

The four links (of many) are mostly responsible for smoothing your font.

In case you don't have any of this, I used to have this in my .fonts.conf:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE fontconfig SYSTEM "fonts.dtd">
<fontconfig>
<!--  Enable sub-pixel rendering --> 
  <match target="font">
    <edit name="rgba" mode="assign"><const>rgb</const></edit>
  </match>
  <match target="font">
    <edit name="antialias" mode="assign">
      <bool>true</bool>
    </edit>
  </match>
    <match target="font">
    <edit name="hinting" mode="assign">
      <bool>true</bool>
    </edit>
   </match>
  <match target="font">
    <edit name="hintstyle" mode="assign">
      <const>hintslight</const>
    </edit>
   </match>
    <match target="font">
    <edit name="autohint" mode="assign">
      <bool>true</bool>
    </edit>
    </match>
    <match target="font">
    <edit mode="assign" name="lcdfilter">
      <const>lcddefault</const>
    </edit>
  </match>
</fontconfig>
```